# Embedded Videos (PB) - Not Available

Tags: themes, widgets

I am using this link to create a wordpress website [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFnKu3-n-HI)
At minute 53 the guy is using "Embedded Videos (PB)" widget in order to embedd a youtube video.
(By the way he is using Page Builder).
Problem is - that widget is not available in the wordpress. 
Where can I find it, or is there any other way I can embed the youtube video in the page with Page Builder???

And I am using Vantage Theme.

Comment: God bless u sir....really gave me a headache thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings -> SiteOrigin Page Builder.

Enable "Bundled Widgets" and save settings.

Embedded Videos (PB) should be available now.